# How do I find the DateTime formatter pattern for this type of Date?

Tags: java, jodatime

I know that for a date of this format "23-07-2014", I can use the formatter as "dd-MM-yyyy".

What can I use as a formatter for this date **"2014-07-05T00:00:00.000-07:00"**?

I am using DateTimeFormatter and want to specify the pattern to parse the above date.

Thanks!

Comment: [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, can you read it, as human being? Can you identify which part matches what? If so, it's trivial to look at the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) and work it out for yourself.

For example, the beginning looks like year, month, day (it could be year, day, month, I suppose, but let's assume it's sane). The documentation states that year is mapped by `y`, and you want 4 numbers, so your format starts with `yyyy`. By the same token, month of the year is `M` and day of month is `d`, so your format starts with `yyyy-MM-dd`.

`T` is just a separator between date and time. You then have something that looks like hour, minutes, seconds - looking at the documentation, that's `HH:mm:ss`.

The following 3 numbers look like milliseconds: `S'.

Finally, a time zone as an offset: `Z`.

Putting it together:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:.SSSZ
```

Thats off the cuff, I've not tried it nor double checked it, but it should work. Or at the very least, it should show you how to go about it, by simply reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is wrong `"dd-mm-yyyy"`. IT should be `"dd-MM-yyyy"`. `MM` use as month and `mm` take as minutes.

You can use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"` to parse `2014-07-05T00:00:00.000-07:00`

```
String str = "2014-07-05T00:00:00.000-07:00";
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
System.out.println(df.parse(str));
```

OutPut:

```
Sat Jul 05 12:30:00 IST 2014
```

Follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You will have answer by your own next time.

Comment: Yes my bad. But what is the pattern for the next input?

Comment: I am not sure if we can write T in the pattern or T refers to Tuesday maybe?

Comment: @Zer0 no it is not. Read my answer in full and refer the link